# Anyone know of an "Office Timeline" plug in for Powerpoint on Mac?

Tags: macos, ms-office, plugins, office-365

Anyone know of an "Office Timeline" plug in for Powerpoint on Mac?  I love https://www.officetimeline.com, but it's for Windows only. Mac must run Fusion or such to support Windows Office, not Mac Office.  I'm looking for suitable functionality for Office Mac Small Business Premium SP3 (build 14.3)

Comment: Welcome to the site - please edit this to show your desired version of Powerpoint if my guess was incorrect.

Comment: Did you find any alternate online or MAC tool for office timeline ?